# How do you actually use dynamically sized types in Rust?

Tags: rust

In theory, Dynamically-Sized Types (DST) have landed and we should now be able to use dynamically sized type instances. Practically speaking, I can neither make it work, nor understand the tests around it.

Everything seems to revolve around the `Sized?` keyword... but how exactly do you use it?

I can put some types together:

```
// Note that this code example predates Rust 1.0
// and is no longer syntactically valid

trait Foo for Sized? {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32;
}

struct Bar;
struct Bar2;

impl Foo for Bar { fn foo(&self) -> u32 { return 9u32; }}
impl Foo for Bar2 { fn foo(&self) -> u32 { return 10u32; }}

struct HasFoo<Sized? X> {
    pub f:X
}
```

...but how do I create an instance of `HasFoo`, which is DST, to have either a `Bar` or `Bar2`?

Attempting to do so always seems to result in:

```
<anon>:28:17: 30:4 error: trying to initialise a dynamically sized struct
<anon>:28   let has_foo = &HasFoo {
```

I understand broadly speaking that you can't have a bare dynamically sized type; you can only interface with one through a pointer, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: You should include the code that correspond to any error messages you've posted.

Comment: Are you sure DST really have landed? I guess a proper announcement would have been made in that case. And [DST issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12938) is not closed yet.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: IIRC, its implementation is incomplete and is behind a feature gate.

Comment: I don't see feature gates in the tests, DSTs seem to be kind of working but are not yet as useful as they could be in their current unfinished state (as noted in the link that @VladimirMatveev provided). See http://is.gd/4IEW99 for an example of use

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Disclaimer: these are just the results of a few experiments I did, combined with [reading Niko Matsakis's blog](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/05/dst-take-5/).

DSTs are types where the size is not necessarily known at compile time.

### Before DSTs

A *slice* like `[i32]` or a *bare trait* like `IntoIterator` were not valid object types because they do not have a known size.

A struct could look like this:

```
// [i32; 2] is a fixed-sized vector with 2 i32 elements
struct Foo {
    f: [i32; 2],
}
```

or like this:

```
// & is basically a pointer.
// The compiler always knows the size of a
// pointer on a specific architecture, so whatever
// size the [i32] has, its address (the pointer) is
// a statically-sized type too
struct Foo2<'a> {
    f: &'a [i32],
}
```

but not like this:

```
// f is (statically) unsized, so Foo is unsized too
struct Foo {
    f: [i32],
}
```

This was true for enums and tuples too.

### With DSTs

You can declare a struct (or enum or tuple) like `Foo` above, containing an unsized type. A type containing an unsized type will be unsized too.

While defining `Foo` was easy, *creating an instance* of `Foo` is still hard and subject to change. Since you can't technically create an unsized type by definition, you have to create a *sized* counterpart of `Foo`. For example,  `Foo { f: [1, 2, 3] }`, a `Foo<[i32; 3]>`, which has a statically known size and code some plumbing to let the compiler know how it can coerce this into its statically unsized counterpart `Foo<[i32]>`. The way to do this in safe and stable Rust is still being worked on as of Rust 1.5 (here is the [RFC for DST coercions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0982-dst-coercion.md) for more info).

Luckily, defining a new DST is not something you will be likely to do, unless you are creating a new type of smart pointer (like `Rc`), which should be a rare enough occurrence.

Imagine `Rc` is defined like our `Foo` above. Since it has all the plumbing to do the coercion from sized to unsized, it can be used to do this:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo")
    }
}
struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let data: Rc<Foo> = Rc::new(Bar);
    // we're creating a statically typed version of Bar
    // and coercing it (the :Rc<Foo> on the left-end side)
    // to as unsized bare trait counterpart.
    // Rc<Foo> is a trait object, so it has no statically
    // known size
    data.foo();
}
```

[playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dbfeff9093e4021d126c&version=stable)

### `?Sized` bound

Since you're unlikely to *create* a new DST, what are DSTs useful for in your everyday Rust coding? Most frequently, they let you write generic code that works both on sized types and on their *existing* unsized counterparts. Most often these will be `Vec`/`[]` slices or `String`/`str`.

The way you express this is through the `?Sized` "bound". `?Sized` is in some ways the opposite of a bound; it actually says that `T` can be either sized or unsized, so it widens the possible types we can use, instead of restricting them the way bounds typically do.

Contrived example time! Let's say that we have a `FooSized` struct that just wraps a reference and a simple `Print` trait that we want to implement for it.

```
struct FooSized<'a, T>(&'a T)
where
    T: 'a;

trait Print {
    fn print(&self);
}
```

We want to define a blanket impl for all the wrapped `T`'s that implement `Display`.

```
impl<'a, T> Print for FooSized<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + fmt::Display,
{
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.0)
    }
}
```

Let's try to make it work:

```
// Does not compile. "hello" is a &'static str, so self print is str
// (which is not sized)
let h_s = FooSized("hello");
h_s.print();

// to make it work we need a &&str or a &String
let s = "hello"; // &'static str
let h_s = &s; // & &str
h_s.print(); // now self is a &str
```

Eh... this is awkward... Luckily we have a way to generalize the struct to work directly with `str` (and unsized types in general): `?Sized`

```
//same as before, only added the ?Sized bound
struct Foo<'a, T: ?Sized>(&'a T)
where
    T: 'a;

impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Print for Foo<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + fmt::Display,
{
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.0)
    }
}
```

now this works:

```
let h = Foo("hello");
h.print();
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e86fa7464c6741a8c108&version=stable)

For a less contrived (but simple) actual example, you can look at the [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait in the standard library.

### Back to your question

```
trait Foo for ?Sized {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}
```

the `for ?Sized` syntax is now obsolete. It used to refer to the type of `Self`, declaring that `Foo can be implemented by an unsized type, but this is now the default. Any trait can now be implemented for an unsized type, i.e. you can now have:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}

//[i32] is unsized, but the compiler does not complain for this impl
impl Foo for [i32] {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        5
    }
}
```

If you don't want your trait to be implementable for unsized types, you can use the `Sized` bound:

```
// now the impl Foo for [i32] is illegal
trait Foo: Sized {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paolo, thanks for your examples, there is 1 point I couldn't keep up


`// Does not compile. "hello" is a &'static str, so self print is str  
// (which is not sized)  
let h_s = FooSized("hello");  
`
cause `FooSized` is defined as:  
struct FooSized<'a, T>(&'a T) where T:'a;  

We have `T` is `str`, so that FooSized will hold a reference to `str` ( which is `&'a str` in this case ) and this has size of a pointer, so why does the compiler complain that it is unsized ?

Comment: @RyanLe because `T` *is* unsized (as you say, it's a `str`). Before DST you could not express that bound because `str` could not be used as a type by itself. Even after DST you can not use `str` directly, it always needs to be behind a pointer, so that does not change.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella to avoid confusion, I would suggest correcting your phrase here what you say: "The way you express this is through the ?Sized "bound". ?Sized is in some ways the opposite of a bound; it actually says that T can be either sized or unsized, so it widens the possible types we can use, instead of restricting them the way bounds typically do."

and change " ... it actually says that T may OR may NOT implement `?Sized` trait, so it widens the possible types we can use ... "

Answer (score 2):

To amend [the example that Paolo Falabella has given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753422/155423), here is a different way of looking at it with the use of a property.

```
struct Foo<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + ?Sized,
{
    printable_object: &'a T,
}

impl<'a, T> Print for Foo<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + ?Sized + fmt::Display,
{
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.printable_object);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let h = Foo {
        printable_object: "hello",
    };
    h.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, to create a `HasFoo` storing a type-erased `Foo` you need to first create one with a fixed concrete type and then coerce a pointer to it to the DST form, that is

```
let has_too: &HasFoo<Foo> = &HasFoo { f: Bar };
```

Calling `has_foo.f.foo()` then does what you expect.

In future these DST casts will almost certainly be possible with `as`, but for the moment coercion via an explicit type hint is required.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example based on [huon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25754581/155423). The important trick is to make the type that you want to contain the DST a generic type where the generic need not be sized (via `?Sized`). You can then construct a concrete value using `Bar1` or `Bar2` and then immediately convert it.

```rust
struct HasFoo<F: ?Sized = dyn Foo>(F);

impl HasFoo<dyn Foo> {
    fn use_it(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.0.foo())
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Could likewise use `&HasFoo` or `Rc<HasFoo>`, etc.
    let ex1: Box<HasFoo> = Box::new(HasFoo(Bar1));
    let ex2: Box<HasFoo> = Box::new(HasFoo(Bar2));

    ex1.use_it();
    ex2.use_it();
}

trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32;
}

struct Bar1;
impl Foo for Bar1 {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32 {
        9
    }
}

struct Bar2;
impl Foo for Bar2 {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32 {
        10
    }
}
```