# How to create a factory function where the data you're creating requires references?

Tags: reference, rust, borrow-checker

There are situations where you want a factory function to create some data, but for whatever reasons the data you return *must* contain references. This does not seem possible because you cannot return references from functions.

Let's look at the following example code:

```
// Important: traits are of unknown size, and so must be passed around 
// as a reference
trait Shape {
    fn area(&self) -> f32;
}
// As seen here.
struct ShapeCollection<'a> {
    shapes: Vec<&'a Shape>
}

// This function needs to return a ShapeCollection, but since the
// data structure requires references to work, it seems impossible!
fn make_shapes<'a>(needRectangle: bool, multiplier: f32) -> ShapeCollection<'a> {
    let rect = Rectangle {
        width: 42.0 * multiplier,
        height: 24.0 * multiplier
    };
    let circle = Circle {
        radius: 42.0 * multiplier
    };

    match needRectangle {
        true => ShapeCollection {
            shapes: vec![&rect, &circle]
        },
        false => ShapeCollection {
            shapes: vec![&circle]
        },
    }
}
// ^ This function won't compile because rect and circle do not
//   life long enough, and the compiler dies at this point

// Impls if you're interested / want to compile, but not that important
struct Rectangle {
    width: f32,
    height: f32
}
impl Shape for Rectangle {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}
struct Circle {
    radius: f32
}
impl Shape for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        (std::f32::consts::PI * self.radius).powf(2f32)
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example built out of a more complex code I am writing. The gist of the issue is two conflating requirements:

- I need polymorphism. Since I'm using traits for this, and traits are not sized, the `Vec` must contain references not values
- I need a factory function. Since I want to generate this list of objects from multiple parts of my code but with different parameters, it makes sense to make a function that encapsulates that, instead of copying and pasting logic around

**How can I solve both of these requirements in Rust?**

The two choices seems to be:

- Do something else to achieve polymorphism, something that is allowed to be passed around as a value
- De-duplicate multiple code blocks in some way that *isn't* creating a parameterised function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply [cannot return a reference to a variable created in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423).

> Important: traits are of unknown size, and so must be passed around as a reference

This isn't strictly true. They must be passed around via some kind of indirection, but a reference (`&`) isn't the only kind of indirection that a *trait object* can use. There's also boxed trait objects:

```
struct ShapeCollection {
    shapes: Vec<Box<Shape>>,
}

fn make_shapes(need_rectangle: bool, multiplier: f32) -> ShapeCollection {
    let rect = Rectangle {
        width: 42.0 * multiplier,
        height: 24.0 * multiplier,
    };
    let circle = Circle {
        radius: 42.0 * multiplier,
    };

    match need_rectangle {
        true => ShapeCollection {
            shapes: vec![Box::new(rect), Box::new(circle)],
        },
        false => ShapeCollection {
            shapes: vec![Box::new(circle)],
        },
    }
}
```

In 99.9% of the cases, a function signature with a lifetime that's only in the return position can never work (or doesn't do what you want) and should *always* give you pause:

```
fn make_shapes<'a>(need_rectangle: bool, multiplier: f32) -> ShapeCollection<'a>
```

Note that the Rust style is `snake_case`, so I've renamed `need_rectangle`.

See also:

- [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567849/155423)
- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility seems to be to use enums instead of traits for polymorphism.

For this example that would be:

```
enum Shape2 {
    Rectangle { width: f32, height: f32 },
    Circle { radius: f32 }
}
fn area(shape: Shape2) -> f32 {
    match shape {
        Shape2::Rectangle {width, height} => width * height,
        Shape2::Circle  {radius} => (std::f32::consts::PI * radius).powf(2f32)
    }
}
struct Shape2Collection {
    shapes: Vec<Shape2>
}

fn make_shapes2(needRectangle: bool, multiplier: f32) -> Shape2Collection {
    let rect = Shape2::Rectangle {
        width: 42.0 * multiplier,
        height: 24.0 * multiplier
    };
    let circle = Shape2::Circle {
        radius: 42.0 * multiplier
    };

    match needRectangle {
        true => Shape2Collection {
            shapes: vec![rect, circle]
        },
        false => Shape2Collection {
            shapes: vec![circle]
        },
    }
}
```

The downside of this is that your implementations aren't methods anymore, but are functions, and that your implementations are smushed together in the same function.