# Blanket implementation returning reference fails with "the parameter type `T` may not live long enough"

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Compilation of this snippet:

```rust
trait Base {
    type T;

    fn get_p(&self) -> &Self::T;
}

trait OnBase: Base {
    fn get_a(&self) -> &A;
}

impl<S, T> OnBase for S
where
    S: Base<T = dyn OnBase<T = T>>,
{
    fn get_a(&self) -> &A {
        self.get_p().get_a()
    }
}

struct A {}
```

Fails with:

```
error[E0311]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/blanket_with_ref.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         self.get_p().get_a()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: the parameter type `T` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/blanket_with_ref.rs:16:14
   |
16 |     fn get_a(&self) -> &A {
   |              ^^^^^
note: ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/blanket_with_ref.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         self.get_p().get_a()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
14 | impl <S, T: 'a> OnBase for S where S:Base<T=dyn OnBase<T=T>> {
   |           ++++
```

I vaguely comprehend that I must somehow tell it that lifetimes of `Base` and `OnBase` should be same but even if I add `'a` to all traits and refrences it keeps failing.

Is it possible to somehow make it compile?

P.S. - it works if get_a returns plain `A`.

pps - in the real app it should be a kind of a strategy delegating to whatever impl it encapsulates

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=afe6cb3288bef8677884384edd818dbb)

Comment: Note that it is impossible to impl `Base` with `T = dyn OnBase`, as it must be `Sized`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you actually want, instead of `T = dyn OnBase<T = T>`:

```rust
trait Base {
    type T;

    fn get_p(&self) -> &Self::T;
}

trait OnBase: Base {
    fn get_a(&self) -> &A;
}

impl<S> OnBase for S
where
    S: Base,
    <S as Base>::T: OnBase,
{
    fn get_a(&self) -> &A {
        self.get_p().get_a()
    }
}

struct A;
```

I'm not sure what purpose `OnBase: Base` serves, though. If `OnBase` is already `Base`, then why do any of this? And what should it return in `get_p`? With the current layout, it's really easy to get caught up in an infinite `get_a` recursion.

Comment: While this is true, a) to be exactly equivalent you need to constrain `S::T: OnBase<T = S::T>`, and b) I'm still interested why the original code doesn't work.

Comment: Those circular typings give me headaches.

Comment: yep, OnBase: Base is redundant, here is more correct mre - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca9ddf1b25dca3046f6482073c598b8e

but still can't understand how 

where S: Base, <S as Base>::T: OnBase<A=A>

is different from 

where S:Base<T=dyn OnBase<A=A>>

in regards to lifetimes? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `dyn OnBase` is a trait object; it does **not** mean objects that implement `OnBase`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769176/what-is-the-difference-between-trait-and-impl-trait-when-used-as-method-argumen) explains it somewhat. You probably think about `impl OnBase`; which I'm not sure is applicable in this scenario, though.

Comment: `dyn OnBase` doesn't even exist just like that, because it isn't `Sized`. It either exists as `&dyn OnBase` or `Box<dyn OnBase>`.

Comment: Thank you! although still can't wrap my head around it... I see that dyn OnBase is not Sized but how it can affect lifetimes? And why does it compile when get_x returns Z itself

Comment: It doesn't make sense to even think about it because it's literally impossible to implement a type with `Base<T = dyn OnBase<T = T>>`. `T` cannot be `dyn OnBase`. It just simply doesn't work.