# What does 'impl MyTrait' do without 'for MyStruct' in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, default-implementation

Traits in Rust allow default implementation for trait methods: you can write some implementation right inside `trait MyTrait {...}` and it will be used in `impl MyTrait for MyStruct` later.

However, you can also write plain `impl MyTrait`, which does not appear to change program's behaviour:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self) {  // Default implementation
        println!("1");
    }
}

impl MyTrait for i32 {
}

fn main() {
    1i32.foo();  // Prints '1'
}

impl MyTrait {  // What is this?
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("2");  // Does nothing?
    }
}
```

What is that `impl MyTrait` without any `for SomeType`? It compiles with only "dead code" warning, so I suppose it has some meaning for the compiler. But I don't understand if there is a way to call it.

Comment: tl;dr - `impl MyTrait {...}` is the old way of writing `impl dyn MyTrait {...}` and is how you add inherent methods to trait objects of `MyTrait`. See also [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567849/what-makes-something-a-trait-object)

Comment: Note that it's [currently impossible to disambiguate](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51402) between the two `foo` calls you have, even though both exist and are distinct.