# What is the meaning of a dyn Trait in argument position?

Tags: rust, traits

I can see the difference between `dyn` and (static) `impl` Traits in return position, such as:

```rust
fn foo() -> Box<dyn Trait> {}
```

vs

```rust
fn foo() -> impl Trait {}
```

Where in the `dyn` version I'm allowed to return different types as long they all implement the Trait, while in the `impl` version I'm only allowed to return the same type (same applies if I return a reference).

But I can't see the purpose of a `dyn Trait` in argument position such as:

```rust
fn foo(x: &dyn Trait) {}
```

vs

```rust
fn foo(x: &impl Trait) {}  // syntatic sugar of `fn foo<T: Trait>(x: &T){}`
```

What is the difference between the two? Why would I use one or the other? And what does the `dyn` version allow me to do that the static one doesn't (that I cannot do for example by relaxing the implicit `Sized` restriction with `?Sized`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567849/what-makes-something-a-trait-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're familiar with C++/Java, then `dyn` corresponds to "interface reference", so it implies dynamic polymorphism (thus requires a bunch of jumps over references, so it's a bit slower).

`impl` being a syntatic sugar, defines a template for functions, thus every time you use the function with another type, you'll get a separate copy of function compiled specifically for this type. So no extra jumping, but your executable bloats with these copies. Rust's ideology tells to create templates with `<T>`, `impl`, unless there're too many versions compiled that the executable is too bloated.

Comment: Are you saying that it's **only** a compromise between binary size and speed? Where in the `impl` version the size is larger, but since I don't have to go through the vtable, it's going to be faster? And that there are no further restrictions with a version of the other?

Comment: @Nick pretty much. it's the same in C++ though, you either make virtual methods in a class, override them and thus you deal with vtable jumps, or you make a function template and forget about vtables

Comment: @Nick For the immediate caller, yes, it's just a matter of the vtable. But an important distinction is that you can make a `dyn Trait` from an `impl Trait`, but not the other way around (because once you go `dyn`, you don't have the compile time type information anymore). That means that the function body cannot call some function that returns a `Box<dyn Trait>` and return that as a `impl Trait`.

Comment: Unless, `Trait` is implemented for `Box<T: Trait + ?Sized>`.