# Why is it possible to implement a trait for both `T: Display` and `str`?

Tags: rust

There is no [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) in [stable Rust yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844), so this does not work:

```
trait X {}

impl<T> X for T {}
impl X for u32 {}  // conflicting implementation
```

No surprises there: `X` is implemented for any type `T` and we can't implement it again for `u32`.

Surprisingly, the following snippet compiles successfuly:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

pub trait Show {}

impl<T: Display> Show for T {}

impl Show for str {}

// These impls would cause "conflicting implementation" errors:
// impl<'a> Show for &'a str
// impl Show for String

fn main() {}
```

I would not expect this code to compile because [`Display` is implemented for `str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#1912-1916), so the generic impl should implement `Show` for `str` and conflict with the specific impl.

Why does `impl Show for str` not conflict with `impl<T: Display> Show for T`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The bound `<T: Display>` implicitly assumes `T` must be a Sized type. However `str` is [unsized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753422/224671). Therefore the two impls are not in conflict with each other.

If you need to cover unsized types like `str` as well, you need to relax the Sized requirement by adding `T: ?Sized`:

```
impl<T: Display + ?Sized> Show for T {}
//              ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Looks like specialization at first sight: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=aba06954d23a33487332595bb687c086&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: @Boiethios that's exactly why I stumbled over this. Actually kinda nice that it allows to "specialize" for string slices.

Comment: @Boiethios It's not specialization. `str` does not satisfy the requirements for `T` in the other impl, so they don't overlap. What you are seeing there is the the `Show` impl for `&str` not `str`.

Comment: But, to be honest, this feels a bit icky. The autoref rules make this very confusing, since you get different behaviour with only sized types.

Comment: @PeterHall I know! That's why I wrote: *looks like*.