# Is there any use for `str` in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, ownership

Is there any case where one would use `str` without borrowing it? Does that even make sense?

I understand the difference between `String` and `&str`, but since there is `&str` there must also be `str`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you actually use dynamically sized types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740916/how-do-you-actually-use-dynamically-sized-types-in-rust)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do much with a *value* of type `str`, but there are plenty of cases where you would want to refer to the type `str`.

- `Box<str>` or `Rc<str>` -  owned types, similar to `String`, but can't be mutated to grow or re-allocate
- Any time you want to accept an arbitrary type that can be *viewed* as a string, you could use constraints like `T: Deref<Target = str>`, `T: AsRef<str>` or `T: Borrow<str>`. For example `HashMap::get` has the following signature:

  ```
  pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> where
    K: Borrow<Q>, // K is the key type for the HashMap
    Q: Hash + Eq,
  ```

  This means you can have a `HashMap<String, i32>`, but access values with a `&str` key, e.g. `map.get("key")`. Here `Q` would be inferred to be `str`, but the `k` argument would still be a `&str` (`&Q`).

  The `?Sized` annotation means that `Q` does not need to have a size known at compile-time, explicitly allowing unsized types like `str` to be used.

Answer (score 4):

Because `str` is unsized (?[Sized](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html)) meaning the size at compile time is not known. You can only use it in places where `?Sized` is allowed. That is the case in [Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html).

```
let s: &str = "any string";
let box: Box<str> = Box::from(s);
```

Because box allocates data on the heap, it does not care if the size of the type is not known at compile time.

You can see `Box<str>` used in [String::into_boxed_str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_boxed_str), which is useful if you want to say, I'm finished with generating the string and don't want to be able to add anything to it. Additionally it removes the capacity field which `String` needs, which saves a bit of memory. However I haven't really seen this used very much.

Most places where you will see a `str` without the `&` before are in traits with generic types. For example when implementing [AsRef](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

```
pub struct CustomString(String);

impl AsRef<str> for CustomString {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        self.0.as_str()
    }
}
```

Sidenote: `str` behaves similarly to a slice `[T]` it to is unsized (`?Sized`).